# Overflow Scroll css is not working in the div as expected

Tags: html, css, angular

I'm developing an app with angular 9, I'm learning angular. I have a fixed header nav app and a scrollable content. I would like to show the vertical scrollbar only in the scrollable content similar to this:

[image]

I tried different configurations, for e.g. I set the div of scrollable content with overflow-y: auto, but   nothing happen. This is my content:

[image]

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the vertical scrollbar to apply to just the scrollable content, you can put everything into a container that’s set to the full viewport height, and then use flex to have a second container that’s used for the content to fit the space left after the navbar. Applying `overflow: auto` to the second container will give it a scrollbar like your illustration.

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.container {
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.nav {
    padding: 1rem;
    background-color: blue;
}

.content {
    padding: 1rem 35%;
    overflow: auto;
    flex-grow: 1;
    font-size: large;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="nav">
        <h1>Nav content</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

        <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?</p>

        <p>At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.</p> 
    </div>
</div>
```